# Silverlight - Out of Browser - Hide current userform and show another?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, hide, userform

I'm used to programming a small amount in VB.net but using Windows form applications. I'm currently working on a small Silverlight 4 project in VB.net but I can't seem to find a function equivalent to that of `Me.Hide()` or `Me.Show()` in Silverlight 4. This is so that I can hide one userform and show another on a button click event.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Frame` and makes pages that user navigates to. They have a back and forward ability like a browser history which makes it cool.

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/nameOfPage", UriKind.Relative))
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a good idea and I've decided to implement it however, `ContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/MainPage.xaml"), UriKind.Relative)` returns the error: "Error 1 Too many arguments to 'Public Function Navigate(source As System.Uri) As Boolean'."

Comment: That is strange! [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Alright! I've got it working, the syntax was slightly off; `ContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))`   Thanks!